# autoincrement id in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php

didn't really succes with assigning values to new ids in my while(row) statement:
Here is an easy example, hope you understand what I want to do. Thanks

```
<?php...

$id=0;
while(rows = mysql_fetch_data){
$id = $id + 1;

$teamname = rows['team'];
?>    

<script>
var team = '<?php echo $teamname; ?>';
var id = 'id_<?php echo $id; ?>';   

//Here I want to save the teamnames as javascript variable "id_1", "id_2" etc, which I can use outside the while statement. 

//For each row id = id_1, id_2, id_3, id_4.
//I want to make id_1 a variable which outputs teamname
//So that 
//var id_1 = team; //team 1
//var id_2 = team; //team 2


<?php    
}
?>

var id_1;
var id_2;
document.write("Teamname 1 = " + id_1 + "</br> Teamname 2 = " + id_2); //Here I want output of teamname 1 and 2.
</script>
```

Comment: not able to understand

Comment: Please don't make fun of people trying to use English as a second (third, fourth) language.

Comment: You seem to be very confused. PHP code runs on the **server side**, and is **completed** by when the Javascript code starts to run on the **client side** (in the browser). Decide in which you would like to maintain the counter (basically answer the question: do you need it in the PHP side?), and use it that way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Really this question is not understable

Comment: Well, the PHP code is fetched and i convert it to javascript variables. I got ajax and animation in real code. But the only thing I need is to save the team names as id_1, id_2

Comment: I just use the php for the first post from another page. Then everything is converted to javascript variables. Everything is going to run in the browser as javascripts @ppeterka66

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Why use document.write in Javascript when you can echo those lines directly from PHP? Instead of id_1, id_2 why not use an array?

Comment: The document.write is nothing i am going to use. Just an example that shows that I get out the correct value from the variables I want (var id_1, id_2 etc). I am going to use the variables later on in the code. @Padrig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an array rather than individual variables, as you have a list of team names:

```
<?php

$teamnames = [];
while(rows = mysql_fetch_data){

  $teamnames[] = rows['team'];
}
?>    
<script>
var teamnames = <?php echo json_encode($teamnames); ?>;
</script>
```

Then you end up with a client-side JavaScript array of team names. While you *could* then output them with `document.write`, there's probably a better option.

But here's your `document.write` updated to use the array:

```
var n;
for (n = 0; n < teamnames.length; ++n)
{
  // Note: There's almost certainly a better choice than `document.write`
  document.write("Teamname " + (n + 1) + " = " + teamnames[n] + "</br>");
}
```

Comment: Well, the document.write is not the important thing here. Sorry if it's confusing. I just want to get the values saved as variables with names: var id_1; var id_2; var id_3; And they are supposed to contain the values of the teams. The variables are outside the while($row)... @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the following and it *should* give you the output that you're after...

```
<script>

<?php
//...

$id_counter = 1;   //Initialise counter
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()){
    echo 'var id_'.$id_counter.' = "'.$rows['team'].'";'; //Echo row in the format: var id_X = "team_name";
    $id_counter++; //Increment the counter
}

?>

document.write("Teamname 1 = " + id_1 + "</br> Teamname 2 = " + id_2); //Here I want output of teamname 1 and 2.
</script>
```

Comment: Well, yes now I get the output. But the important thing is to save the values of "teamnames example" to different id's outside my while($row) statement. Everything is needed in javascript variables becuase of that everything is going to run in browser later on. @Steven

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this will output each team_name as a JS variable?

Comment: I don't get it with the fetch_assoc(),. My data is not imported and the echo just echoing "var id_X = 'example'". The "document.write" is not beeing applied. @Steven